# Visual Studio 2012 компиляция С/С++ файлов из консоли

Tags: windows, консоль, visual-studio, c++

Как можно скомпилировать С/С++ файл в Windows 8 используя VS2012 из консоли?

Например, такой:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

Нет желания ставить MinGW или Cygwin, т.к. компилятор уже есть (он же в Visual Studio).

**UPD:**
Сначала в консоли из папки *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin* запустить файл *vcvars32.bat*

Потом использовать:

```
cl main.cpp
```

Всякие ключи для компилятора:
[Compiler Options Listed by Category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: >> C/C++ файл

А где здесь С файл?

Comment: вопрос, не как скомпилировать конкретный файл, а как скомпилировать файл из консоли который использует только STL.
Например, как в Linux, g++ main.cpp -o main

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639(v=vs.80).aspx
cl.exe находится в папке Visual Studio 2012\VC\bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В VS2010 в XP делается так

```
cl main.cpp /Feprog_name
```

Comment: Чудесно. Только (насчёт 2010 не знаю) в более старых надо было ещё нужные переменные установить (путь и т.д.). И VS куда-то клала специальносозданный батник с этими установками. Толи VSVARS.BAT, то ли ещё какой.

Comment: Так VS предоставляет свою командную строку, где все переменные уже установлены. Если нужно пользоваться обычной строкой, то можно либо пути прописать, либо прямо в строке писать cl с путем:

    c:\Program Files\...\cl

Comment: Даже если запускать cl напрямую, ругается на отсутствующую mspdb100.dll. Соответственно, к ней (и скорее всего и к другим библиотекам) путь тоже должен быть прописан. После выполнения vcvars32.bat ругаться перестает.

Comment: Так можно эту dll в папку с экзешником кинуть.

Comment: Это разве что если вдруг понадобится собрать портативную версию компилятора от MS. А так есть PATH

Comment: Да, вся беда была в vcvars32.bat, не знал что надо запускать, спасибо.